# Visual Studio 2015 Hide Javascript Errors from Error List

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, javascript-intellisense

I have recently started working with mvc6 and knockoutJS in Visual Studio 2015.
When I use knockout in my typescript files I get red underlines on everything jquery or knockout (or any library) related, and it says `Cannot find name 'ko'` in my Error List. I understand that the IDE can't work out that these javascript objects do exist, but surely this is a problem everybody gets?

How can I remove intellisense from my javascript/typescript files?

Comment: Just to clarify, I realise I can select `Build Only` in my error list, but I would like the incorrect intellisense removed from my typescript files too

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: From Settings**

You will need to disable the Javascript Language Service by going to **Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service** and un-check "Enable the new JavaScript language service"

[image]

**Option 2: Disable it through the registry**

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\TypeScriptLanguageService]

Create/Edit the dword UseTypeScriptExperimental to 00000000

“UseTypeScriptExperimental”=dword:00000000